# New Year Chaos Challenge in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am working on this challenge: [New Year Chaos Challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen). I have reached quite far, and realized that my code is not working for all test cases, **usually for larger inputs**.

I know I write bad code, but this is how I will learn. So here is my algorithm for this:

```
1. Take i = len(a)-1
2. Check whether the last element is at place or not a[i] not equals len(a)(which is anyway the nth element)
3. Find how far it is from it's actual place
4. If the value is more than 2, then Chaotic and exit
5. Else if the value is positive, which means the guy has to move to the right and bribe would be taken into consideration, else not valuable
6. Add the number of value the element has
7. Swap the values using normal swapping 
8. Print the statement according to the situation
```

**My Code:**

```
def minimumBribes(a):
  min_bribe = 0
  isChaotic = False
  i = len(a)-1
  #for chaos check
  while i >= 0:
    posVal = 0
    if a[i] != len(a):
      #if the value comes more than two with respect to any position then chaotic
      posVal = i - a.index(i+1)
      if abs(posVal) > 2:
        isChaotic = True
        break
      elif posVal > 0:
        min_bribe += posVal
        #swapping them to their place original place
        temp = i+1
        a[a.index(i+1)] = a[i]
        a[i] = temp

     i -= 1
    print("Too Chaotic" if isChaotic else min_bribe-1, end="")
```

So for some test cases my algorithm works totally fine like:

```
1. [2 1 5 3 4]
2. [2 5 1 3 4]
3. [5 1 2 3 7 8 6 4]
4. [1 2 5 3 7 8 6 4]
```

**Error Caught in one of the test cases like this:** [Input](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/15305/input02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1568926727&Signature=nvwERILtfV1l3BUcrZfQPRLCvoc%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

**Expected Output:** 966 but my code did not run through it. Took a lot of time.

**Failures of my Algorithm:**

> 1. Time Consuming for large inputs
> 2. Space Consumptions

Any help which will tell me:

> 1. Efficient code for the solution or error rectification of my code
> 2. How you think of this solution, and what it will take me to get to this level.

I am a learner and I will learn. I am fascinated by people who can really code smoothly and comes with brilliant logics. Please guide me as well. Thanks :)

Comment: `list.index()` is not a very efficient method so replacing that with something more optimal will save time well. In general, look at the discussions section of HackerRank or LeetCode to see how others have solved the problem to see where you could get better.

Comment: As you don't actually have any problem and just want to optimize, maybe you have more luck on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) :)

Answer (score -2):

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

## Complete the minimumBribes function below.

def minimumBribes(q):
q = [i-1 for i in q]  # set queue to start at 0

```
bribes = 0



for i, o in enumerate(q):

    cur = i 

    if o - cur > 2:

        print("Too chaotic")

        return

    for k in q[max(o - 1, 0):i]:

        if k > o:

            bribes += 1


print(bribes)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
t = int(input())

```
for t_itr in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    q = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    print(minimumBribes(q))
```